# Is there any way to display pdf files in browser such that the viewer can only read the file and can't save/download/print the file in any form

Tags: javascript, php, pdfviewer

I have to integrate pdf files in my PHP web application such that the viewer of the file can not save/download/print the pdf file.

I am finding a way of doing this in any way like using javascript, jquery or straight in PHP or any other way if any.

Comment: I know that I require some custom pdf viewer or a third party library to do that but I want to know the name of the available one.

Comment: I am finding the solution just like [here](http://www.bookrix.com/book.html?bookID=jemma._1302110953.2788898945).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need a custom PDF viewer in your app, like what Google Drive does with images and documents.
I'm not aware of any functionality that allows an app to tell Chrome/Firefox or the registered PDF handler to limit user interaction like you mention.

Comment: And if you do integrate such a custom PDF viewer, make sure you "stream" the pages. If the viewer in turn just downloads a PDF from your server behind the scenes, the user could do the same.